# Can anyone explain what is animatable in contents property in CALayer? How is it animatable?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I am learning about core animation. But i am seeing a word animatable in  the explanation. Please explain. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410773-contents

Comment: Its not something *in* this property that is animatable. The property itself **is** animatable.

Comment: "The property itself is animatable" can u tell what u mean by this?

Answer (score 1):

For `CALayer` properties, it simply means that [those "animatable" properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH11-SW1) can be animated via Core Animation (e.g. [`CABasicAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cabasicanimation)). For example, this transitions the [`backgroundColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410966-backgroundcolor) property (which is animatable) of a `CALayer` from whatever it was to `.red` over a period of two seconds:

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
animation.toValue = UIColor.red.cgColor
animation.duration = 2
view.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

See the [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more information.

---

I know you asked about `CALayer`, but you'd also see "animatable" in reference to `UIView` properties, too. In this context, it means that those can be animated with [`UIViewPropertyAnimator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator) or the older, block-based animation methods such as [`animate(withDuration:animations:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622418-animate).

Where possible, it's generally preferable to animate `UIView` properties, rather than `CALayer` properties, because these `UIView` animation techniques offer nice, block-based renditions and tend to correspond more directly with what we use in UIKit on a day-to-day basis. But when needed/desired, you can certainly dive into `CALayer` Core Animation, as shown above.

Comment: I would close it. But right now i Dont have enough reputation to close it.

Comment: I’m unsure why you’re reluctant to accept this answer, but so be it.